# AS3 Audio Synch & preloading

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a video that is an swf file with length 03:02 (3 minutes & 2 seconds) 4552 Frames.
Now in different timing of this video I want to synch 4 audio files.
Is there any possibility to synchronize all sounds on the video?
My audio files must be placed in exactly positions. For example the second audio must be loaded at 01:27:30.
I have extended my timeline to 4552 frames (03:02) and I am using the code below in different frames to load my audio files:

```
var soundClip:Sound=new Sound();

//Create a new SoundChannel Object
var sndChannel:SoundChannel=new SoundChannel();

//Load sound using URLRequest
soundClip.load(new URLRequest("secondsound.mp3"));
sndChannel=soundClip.play();
```

And if there is a way to synch my audio files is there any possibility to preload the whole movie with all sounds and with my .swf file?

Answer (score 0):

track the netstream time property and call your sounds when the video reaches the times you want to hear them.